# Cannot open the project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to open a Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.4, But it's not opening, It shows   (needs migration).

[image]

When I try to reload it gives this popup.

[image]

When I click the Ok button, it redirects me to this page.

[image]

When I click on the link, it redirects me to this page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/porting-migrating-and-upgrading-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2015.

I have gone through the above link, but I am not able to solve the issue.

I am able to open this project in Visual Studio 2015.

Visual Studio 2017 About window.

[image]

**csproj file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{D6C2377F-23C1-4998-A72F-622632553B58}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>AppContainerExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>NECMobilePOS.Client.Windows</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>NECMobilePOS.Client.Windows</AssemblyName>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <AppxPackageDir>bin\Release\</AppxPackageDir>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    <AppxBundle>Auto</AppxBundle>
    <PackageCertificateThumbprint>54D50F2637891A440C3FCC71BB05D56DE984BFC0</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
    <PackageCertificateKeyFile>NECMobilePOS.Client.Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP;POSTYPE_RESTO;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP;POSTYPE_RESTO;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;WINDOWS_APP;POSTYPE_RESTO;</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP;POSTYPE_RESTO;</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
    <WarningLevel>3</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>
    </DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_APP;POSTYPE_RESTO;</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '12.0' ">
    <VisualStudioVersion>12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>NECMobilePOS.Client.Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\SQLitePCL.raw.0.8.6\build\win81\SQLitePCL.raw.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\SQLitePCL.raw.0.8.6\build\win81\SQLitePCL.raw.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.2.0.45\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.2.0.45\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\SQLitePCL.raw.0.8.6\build\win81\SQLitePCL.raw.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\SQLitePCL.raw.0.8.6\build\win81\SQLitePCL.raw.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.2.0.45\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.2.0.45\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: @Saruman u meant project file? its .csproj

Comment: yeah sorry didnt read the post correctly

Comment: Do you have xamarin installed ? Ie mobile development tools in visual studio installer?

Comment: I think yes, that's why I am able to create a new Xamarin project and I am able to run it. One more thing that I am able to open the same project in VS 2015... I select Xamarin while installing VS 2017. Do I need to install anything else explicitly?

Comment: @viveknuna- You need to install xamarin.ios & windows package too in visual studio.

Comment: @Arvindraja Can you provide me the link, where can I get these?

Comment: Follow  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows) link & select most of package from right side about windows & .net framework [image](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/am/c4eruo2pr7tr.png)

Comment: @Arvindraja I have updated my question with the Visual Studio 2017 About window,

Comment: @Arvindraja Have you checked my updated question, Please let me know if I still need to follow the steps mentioned in the link shared by you?

Comment: You can follow, There is no side effect. you might missing some required packages as I mentioned that image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180176/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-arvindraja).

Comment: You are missing UWP packages.

Comment: How to check and install? @saketkumar

Comment: Do you need that window project? Are you supposed to work on the same?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/verify-your-xamarin-environment?view=vs-2017

Comment: Run the installer again, it will tell you what else to download, be careful with all what it suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the reason behind the issue.

I had Xamarin windows 8.1 app project which was built on VS 2015. But I was trying to open it in VS 2017. And VS 2017 does not support windows 8.1 app, it supports UWP apps.

So you have two options.

1. You need to convert the Windows 8.1 app to UWP app manually if you
   want to work only in VS 2017.
2. Just be happy with VS 2015 and develop your Windows 8.1 app.